# How to convert string to date with Tibbo AggreGate expression language

Tags: expression, platform

I have a table of string data. It is essentially a csv file.
Example string: "01.10.2021 5:41:15";"255,1759949"
I need to convert datatype from string to date

Need to replace original string with date column

Answer (score -1):

The simpliest way is to add and drop column:

```
   removeColumns(
      addColumns(
        table("<<str1><S>><<str2><S>>","01.10.2021 5:41:15","255,1759949","01.10.2021 5:41:15","255,1759949")
        ,"<d><D>"
        ,"parseDate({str1}, 'dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss', 'GMT+3' )"
      )
      ,"str1"
    )
```